# Silex token authentication

Tags: symfony, silex

I create my first app with silex. Only logged in users can use the app. In the first page i create a login form, so the user can authenticate. My security provider look like:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
        'security.firewalls' => array(
            'secure_area_edison' => array(
                'pattern' => '^/admin/',
                'form' => array('login_path' => '/', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
                'users' => function () use ($app) {
                    return new App\Services\UserProvider($app['db']);
                },
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Every url after '/admin' require that the user was successfull authenticated. Everything works fine and now i want to extend my app with an API. I create a new controller which retrieves data from database and return a JSON reponse, this work also fine.

But how can the user authenticate for this API? Should i create a new column in my user table like "hash" or "token"? Users which will retrieve the JSON Response must send the token in every get request, is this the correct way?

The url can look:

```
/admin/api/allProducts/token/<TOKEN>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use token base authentication instead of passing token in every get request.
refer : https://github.com/thcolin/silex-simpleuser-jwt